# How to reset LD_PRELOAD

Tags: 12.04, environment-variables, dynamic-linking, ld

I've done the following command to set the path for LD_PRELOAD. But it's the wrong path.

```
export LD_PRELOAD=/home/
```

Does anyone know what is the default path for LD_PRELOAD on Ubuntu 12.04? What is the exact command to reset the export?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no default LD_PRELOAD variable, or, in other words, it is empty. You can revert to that state by typing

```
unset LD_PRELOAD
```

LD_PRELOAD is not to specify the libraries found in the regular case; it is just here to specify an order of library loading that is different from the regular one (determined by [ldconfig(8)](http://linux.die.net/man/8/ldconfig)).

Comment: after i've entered `unset LD_PRELOAD`, i'm still getting the `Platform/ERROR: ld.so: object '/' from LD_PRELOAD cannot be preloaded: ignored`

Comment: What are you trying to run? My bet would be that you are running a script that tries to set up its own LD_PRELOAD and fails.

Comment: i'm running cmake that requires the boost library...